# App running in Google App Engine fails, tries ah_start for minutes, then restarts

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a message processor task that runs in the app engine.  There are many times that it appears to die, then go into a long (several minutes) log trying to do ah_start, then finally restarts.

This task responds to messages from the message queue, then writes data from these messages to a mySql database.

Looking at the log histogram, it appears that this task is in a 15 minute cycle, where it works for a bit, then does this ah_start loop for a bit, then goes back to working.

When I start sending a heavy load of messages to process, it looses messages which is not an optimal situation for a production environment.

I really don't know even where to check to find out what is going on.

I am sorry but search as I can I really can not find good information on how to use the _ah/start process.  A good link to to an explanation and example would to worth a lot.

My process is very simple,
start up
wait for message
store data in data base
ack message
go back to wait for next message

Here is a copy of my app.yaml file:

```
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10


service: message-processor

runtime: nodejs10


env_variables:
  BUCKET_NAME: "stans_temp"

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  script: auto
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have a url handler for `/_ah/start ` that sends a valid 200 response?

Comment: It's hard to say anything, but usually in App Engine everything starts in app.yaml... Can you add the file?

Answer (score 0):

I would start with correcting syntax errors in `app.yaml`.

As I can see: `runtime: nodejs10` and there is no `env: flex` settings this seems to be App Engine Standard environment. ([`app.yaml` for standard reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#syntax))

However I can see that you have `resources` setting with is only for App Engine Flexible. ([`app.yaml` for flexible reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/app-yaml#syntax))

App Engine Flex and App Engine Standard are practically two different products, so you need to decide which one you want to use. The article about it you may find [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments). This might be reason, I am even surprised that this was deployed successfully.